# Обработка js внутри src картинки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Дорогие друзья, задался таким вопросом, просто в качестве размышления. Как интересно можно выполнить js скрипт внутри тега src картинки, интересно можно ли победить? Может есть какие-то хак-методы?)

я пробовал так но не сработало

```
<img src=" '<script>alert('1');</script>" alt="">
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Что значит «вывести скрипт внутри src»?

Comment: в смысле выполнить, простите поправил

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12658992/1016033 вроде в новых браузерах никак

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смысла в этом, конечно, мало.

```js
function testClick() {
  eval(document.getElementById("testImg").getAttribute("src"));
}
```

```html
<img id="testImg" src="alert('1');" alt="">
<button onclick="testClick()">Click</button>
```